# Multiple developers with a single Git account?

Tags: git, user-accounts

I've just joined an organisation that is looking to move to Git - Hooray! However, they want all the developers to commit using same user account - Boo! I'm having a hard time convincing them that this is not a standard practice.

Are there any problems that come about from committing to a Git repo in this fashion? If anyone has any showstoppers I'd be really happy as something about this feels very wrong to me and I'd love to be able to stick with convention.

Answer (score 5):

When say a "Git account", do you mean a single account at a git repo hosting service like github, or do you mean that they propose to have everyone use the same name/email in their git config, so all commits appear to come from the same person?

If the latter, I would politely ask for a strong rationale, and then if one wasn't forthcoming, I'd seriously reconsider how badly I needed the job.  Stupidity that strong is unlikely to be confined to one small area.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't too clear, by "Git account" I mean user account. It's not a repo hosting service - it's self-hosted. Rather than create additional users on a box for each dev. The idea is that each dev works on a share, he/she then SSH's into a box and commits from there.

The "strong rationale" I got boiled down to as they are currently doing things the wrong way, doing them the right way would create problems.

Comment: Just to clarify, as you have to SSH into a box to commit all commits won't just appear to come from the same person, they will come from the same person as far as Git is concerned.

Comment: You could have separate repos (with separate user/email configs) under the same user account and push to a central repo, if you really wanted.  But "doing them the right way would create problems" would make me go "aaieee!" and look for another job.

Comment: Agreed. Shame there's not a reason that would make this technically impossible that can't be argued with. Think I'm going to have to live with this one for now.

Answer (score 1):

If more than one developer/user are going to work on a project it is a must for each of them to commit(push in case of git) with their account details. As in case of any disputes the **account details** is the efficient way to find out with which account the last commit was done.

Comment: Yeah I did point out there it would be difficult to find out who had committed what. They replied that they can just "shout across the room" in order to find out.

Comment: "What braindead, moronic oxygen thief produced this pile of... oh wait, never mind, it was me".